# how to add attributes to a category in magento with sql?

Tags: php, sql, magento, attributes, categories

How can i add a attribute to a category in magento ?

I have read some tutorials and they said just insert two records but that doesn't work
Already changed a lot and playing with the values but still no result

After each change i have cleared the cache so that is nog the problem

I am working with magento 1.5 and flat tables

inserted the next querys and testing with the values

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` 
(
    `attribute_id`, 
    `entity_type_id`, 
    `attribute_code`, 
    `attribute_model`, 
    `backend_model`, 
    `backend_type`, 
    `backend_table`, 
    `frontend_model`, 
    `frontend_input`, 
    `frontend_label`, 
    `frontend_class`, 
    `source_model`, 
    `is_required`, 
    `is_user_defined`, 
    `default_value`, 
    `is_unique`, 
    `note`
) 
VALUES
(
    158, 
    3, 
    'uitslag', 
    NULL, 
    '', 
    'varchar', 
    '', 
    '', 
    'text', 
    'Uitslag', 
    '', 
    '', 
    1, 
    0, 
    '', 
    0, 
    ''
);
```

And

```
INSERT INTO `eav_entity_attribute` 
(
    `entity_attribute_id`, 
    `entity_type_id`, 
    `attribute_set_id`, 
    `attribute_group_id`, 
    `attribute_id`, 
    `sort_order`
) 
VALUES
(
    158, 
    3, 
    3, 
    3, 
    158, 
    61
);
```

Anyone a idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, what about catalog_category_entity* tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('category', 'uitslag', array(
                     'label'     => 'Uitslag',
                     'type'  => 'varchar',
                     'input'     => 'text',
                     'visible'  => true,
                     'required' => false,
                     'position' => 1,
));
```

The simply add values to categories either through the Magento admin, or directly into the catalog_category_entity_varchar table.